# Creating listview using arraylist

Tags: arraylist

I have 2 arrays as follows, I want to create a list view showing the details from both array together eg
Location:-------
Magnitude:-------
How can i do that?

```
           String des = description.toString();
           Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=Location: ).*?(?= ;)").matcher(des);
           List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
           while (matcher.find()) {
               list.add(matcher.group());
           }

           String des1 = description.toString();
           Matcher matcher1 = Pattern.compile("(?<=Magnitude: ).*?(?= ;)").matcher(des1);
           List<String> listmagnitude = new ArrayList<>();
           while (matcher1.find()) {
               listmagnitude.add(matcher1.group());
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
int i = 0;

for(String l: list) {
   System.out.format("Location: %s \t Magnitude: %s\n", l, listMagnitude[i]);
   i++;
}
```